Animating material property from a linked collection
I have a linked collection with several objects and I want to animate hue value of one of the materials.
Following this answer I have a custom property linked to my hue driver and this works perfectly when used locally.
But when I link the collection in my final scene (separate file), I cannot access this custom property.
I tried this solution but I think it maybe only works with single objects in collection.
Maybe I am missing something ?

Yes, you are missing something.
If you want to update (and animate) a material from a linked collection you just go to 3D viewport panel and select Object > Library Override > Make

